# How to send email through javascript without using a program?

Tags: javascript, email

How can I simple send an email without Outlook or something with JavaScript?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Shame the nick is "shady" because I can't believe a person would really want to do this nefariously. Also, server-side script is invariably the correct answer.

Comment: I want to add an auto-invite in my blog, and really dont know how

Comment: Shay-dee! This is totally shady! It's beyond shady

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a server-side script to send the email, then call it using AJAX.

Beware of spammers, though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't send an email using only JavaScript. Your JavaScript will need to send the email data (subject, replyto, message, etc.) to a server script (PHP, Python, etc.) which can then send your message from the mailserver.

Here's how using PHP:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm